# appending to an IList in DB throws referential integrity constraint violation using EF in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the POCO class set up like this:

```
public class Survey
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Image> Images { get; set; }
}

public class Image
{
    [Key]
    public int ImageID { get; set; }
    public int SurveyID { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public virtual Survey Survey { get; set; }
}
```

I can create the entry in the database with all the fields set appropriately. When I try to edit the items in the Images, I run into the referential integrity constraint violation. For example I initially created the data with 2 images. In the edit I add another image to the collection. In the edit view I only set the ImageUrl because I expect the EF to create the appropriate ImageID and SurveyID when I save using:

```
 db.Entry(survey).State = EntityState.Modified;
 db.SaveChanges();
```

I have checked that the Image[0 and 1].ImageId, SurveyID, ImageUrl are bound appropriately. Image[2].ImageId, and SurveyID are set to 0 but I expect the EF to set them upon saving it on the DB.

I have played around with the options using modelbuilder but there is something I'm not getting right. Your help is appreciated.

This is the error I get:
Additional information: A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property value(s) of 'Survey.ID' on one end of a relationship do not match the property value(s) of 'Image.SurveyID'

**EDIT** edit code attached

```
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,Name, Images")] Survey survey)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(survey).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(survey);
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your edit action code.

Comment: added the "edit" actionresult

Comment: You got the error when you try to edit the survey or the image? wasn't clear at the question

Comment: I think you are trying to edit the survey POCO. do you bound  the surveyID from the form back to your edit method ?

Comment: yes it is bound. I'm trying to append to the IList Images.

Comment: Can you post the edit method for Image?

Comment: There is no edit/create method for image. I'm using ajax to add to the fields in my view which are then passed to the survey create method and are added. The image gets created automatically because it is bound and shares the foreign key with survey so EF creates it automatically

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by adding the Images separately in my edit actionresult.

```
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,Name,Images")] Survey survey)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < survey.Images.Count; i++ )
            {
                if ((survey.Images[i].SurveyID == 0) && (survey.Images[i].ImageID == 0))
                {
                    survey.Images[i].SurveyID = survey.ID;
                    db.Images.Add(survey.Images[i]);
                }
            }

            db.Entry(survey).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(survey);
    }
```